# Issue with opening modal in plunker

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, plunker

I'm trying to recreate an issue with angular modal but I can't get plunker to work for basic modal. This gives error of index 0, but can't figure out where I should be passing these items from. In the code that I'm using, I don't get this issue. But when I use the same code with Plunker, it throws this error.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log',
  function($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    $scope.open = function(size) {

      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
          items: function() {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
      }, function() {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });
    };
  }
]);

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',
  function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
      item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function() {
      $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      < div class = "modal-header" > < h3 class = "modal-title" > I 'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: You are loading the ui js twice, not sure it has anything to do with your issue. ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js is just templates included.

Comment: Yes I didn't know if that was needed to included twice. Remove that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `items` in the

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',
```

**'items',**

```
function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log',
  function($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    $scope.open = function(size) {

      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
          items: function() {
            return $scope.items;
          }
        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
      }, function() {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });
    };
  }
]);

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'items',
  function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
      item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function() {
      $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class = "modal-header" > <h3 class = "modal-title"> I 'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue. But I can't still open the modal and instead when I click on the modal button, it throws the HTML back. I'm not sure if this is a CSS issue. [link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/glcw3bjPVPDesq05lg47?p=preview)

Comment: Don't exactly know why that was happening but now updated the plunker so you may not be able to look at that issue. I'm not going to worry about it now. Thanks for your help!